# Alternative code for services.BuildServiceProvider (in ConfigureServices) when migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I have modular ASP.NET Core application. Back in the day of .NET Core 1.1 I build services (`AddScoped`, `AddSingleton` ...) in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    GlobalConfiguration.ModuleInitializers = sp.GetServices<IModuleInitializer>();
    foreach (var moduleInitializer in GlobalConfiguration.ModuleInitializers)
        moduleInitializer.ConfigureServices(services, this.Configuration, this.Environment);
}
```

each module (library) has own class which implements 'IModuleInitializer' and register services:

```
public class ModuleInitializer : IModuleInitializer
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<....>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<...>();
        ...
```

With migration from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 I am receiving warning:

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an
>   additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider
>   alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to
>   'Configure'

I already educate myself what that means, where is the problem ..., but I am having problems how to properly configure services in a module design application.

I also need to get information about modules from internet. My question is if this approach is good, or is there any better/recommended?

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;    //From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    var serverSett = this.Configuration.GetSection("Server").Get<ServerSettings>();
    string[] allowedModules;
    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        allowedModules = //Get allowed modules from web
    }
    if (allowedModules.Any(t => t == "Shopping");
        services.AddShopping();    //Extension method in Shopping library which register own services.
    if (allowedModules.Any(t => t == "Offer");
        services.AddOffer();    //Extension method in Offer library which register own services.
}
```

Comment: It's unclear where you call the `BuildServiceProvider` method. Is it in a `Controller`? Somewhere else? Also, where do you register the `IModuleInitializer` services?

Comment: Not sure if you can register services anywhere else that  `ConfigureServices` of `Startup` class? Code is inside `ConfigureServices` method. (I also edit question to indicate this).

Answer (score 0):

Using the DI to setup the DI is a bit of a problem and could definitely be problematic.

Why not just use some reflection to get the IModuleInitializers.

```cs
var moduleInitializers = typeof(MyAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(type =>
        !type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract &&
        typeof(IModuleInitializer).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    .Select(type => Activator.CreateInstance(type))
    .Cast<IModuleInitializer>()
    .ToArray();

foreach (var moduleInitializer in moduleInitializers)
    moduleInitializer.ConfigureServices(services, this.Configuration, this.Environment);
```

As for your second question I cannot give you an advice. But I would question the need to dynamically setup the app unless you really really need that.